# Is there a way to dynamically detect which element is firing an event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, frontend

I have a piece of code, which updates user info on the fly. It's not so much of a problem as a code smell, but I'm having to use the same code with different elements in my current code! I'd like to make this function Polymorphic for future maintenance (imagine if there's 50+ items on the page!)

My ideal solution would look something like this (pseudo-code)

```
function (/* element firing the save event */, /* changed property on my MVC Model */) {
    $('.ChangedElement').on('save', function (e, params) {
        var Property = $("#ModelProperty").text().replace(" ", "");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Dealer/UpdateDealer",
            data: {
                UpdatedValue: params.newValue,
                UpdatedPropertyName: Property
            },
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Any and all help with this would be much appreciated as I have absolutely no idea where to start with this.

Comment: The element that the event was triggered on is available in the event handler function under `this` - if you need that as a jQuery object, then `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) will point to the element calling the event so use the attribute method to fetch the id of the element.

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Comment: I presume I can use $(this).on('save') as well?

Comment: No. The jquery element.on ("") attaches an event to a function not calls back on the element calling the event. Also "save" is not a DOM event.